# Errors of mixed content while loading page in iframe from https to https

Tags: javascript, iframe, https, mixed-content

I am trying to load page in iframe through https on https page, but get error of mixed content.
(https://prnt.sc/h4qdir)

The requested [url](https://cars.volkswagen.ru/credit/garant/touareg?complect=touareg_v6&price=3598500&mode=iframe&view=no-form)

Error:

`## Mixed Content: The page at 'https://auto-dina.ru/purchase/finance/credit/calc/?back_url=~y7YDI&pl=Y&MODEL=touareg&COMP=touareg_v6&PRICE=3598500' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure resource 'http://cars.volkswagen.ru/credit/garant/touareg/?complect=touareg_v6&price=3598500&mode=iframe&view=no-form'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS. ##`

Comment: the error is quite clear .... have you checked the developer tools network tab for any surprises?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found that URL hadn't slash '/' after model code.
Apparently, on requested site in .htaccess file rule for redirect to '/' is above https rule, or something like that.
In any case, adding slash in URL address solved my problem